# Create a new column==1 when another column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to  create a new column displaying 1 if another column is a missing value.

I have the following dataframe

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 5.5 |
| 2.5 | 1.6 |
| NaN | 2.0 |

I want to get the following result :

| Col1 | Col2 | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 5.5 | 1.0 |
| 2.5 | 1.6 | 0.0 |
| NaN | 2.0 | 1.0 |

I tried the following code :

```py
df['new_col']=[1 if (pd.isnull(df['col1'])==True) else 0 for i in range(len(df))]
```

I got the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match **any** missing value per row:

```
df['new_col'] = df.isna().any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   Col1  Col2  new_col
0   5.5   NaN        1
1   2.5   1.6        0
2   NaN   2.0        1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['col3']=np.where(df['Col1'].isna(), 1, 0)
df
```

```
    Col1    Col2    col3
0   NaN     5.5     1
1   2.5     1.6     0
2   NaN     2.0     1
```

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['Col1'].isna().astype(int)` ;)